# HTTP POST with boundary getting error

Tags: c++, http, post, arduino

I am trying to post an image to my server using an Arduino board. The page I'm posting to is using Ruby on Rails and I know it works as I have tested it with Postman. Now, my Arduino code does fine until I start adding boundaries. Guidance please. I have tried multiple different setups. I have removed the code for uploading the file as I can't get what is below to work yet.

```
// send the header
sprintf(outBuf,"POST %s HTTP/1.1",page);
client.println(outBuf);
sprintf(outBuf,"Host: %s",domainBuffer);
client.println(outBuf);
client.println(F("Connection: close\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----AbC123"));
sprintf(outBuf,"Content-Length: %u\r\n",strlen(thisData));
client.println(outBuf);

// send the body (variables)
client.println(F("------AbC123"));
client.println(F("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"authenticate\""));
client.println();
client.println(F("authenticate"));
client.println(F("------AbC123--"));
```

Here is what I am getting from my webpage. I know my issue lies in the structure of my request.

```
 2018-03-21 01:56:23 +0000: Rack app error: #<EOFError: bad content body>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:147:in `get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:58:in `block in parse'
```

Comment: What is `thisData`? You are not sending `thisData` to the server. The `Content-Length` must match the MIME data you are actually sending (99, assuming `client.println` sends CRLF line breaks). Can you show the actual HTTP request that `client` is actually transmitting?

Comment: char* thisData  = "------AbC123\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"authenticate\"\r\nauthenticate\r\n------AbC123--";

Comment: Piece of crap. Thank you. I just realized the content-length was the problem. I had it duplicated in thisData but I had left off the extra blank line between content-dispostion and the actual value. Basically i forgot 1 "\r\n"

Comment: That was it! Just finished testing and all of the code works. If you move your comment to an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: If `thisData` contains the MIME data you want to send, then you should be sending `thisData` instead of duplicating the MIME data, eg: `sprintf(outBuf, "Content-Length: %u\r\n", strlen(thisData)+2); client.println(outBuf); client.println(thisData);`

Comment: It contains the variables but not the structure of the request. I just put the whole thing in it for testing but in production I will be using EEPROM to store user input data that will then be sent out using this POST request.

Comment: that doesn't negate what I said. If you have a variable that holds the body content of a request then send that variable after the headers, and use that same variable to calculate the Content-Length.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future looking at this question. My issue was I was calculating the content-length incorrectly for the body. Content-length is the length of everything from the beginning boundary to the closing boundary. Once I fixed that everything worked perfectly. Thanks for all the help.